# Localhost Cookie

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies, localhost

I am using PHP under localhost (XAMPP).
I am trying to set a cookie with .localhost as its domain.

```
setcookie($key, $value, $expire, $path, '.localhost', $secure, $httponly);
```

Because of multiple subdomains on real sites.
It works by Firefox But it fails by IE8.
I can restrict it by PHP coding then it would be neglected if localhost is as server domain. 
But I am not sure that whether cause many problems on real site servers? Can I use it on real servers? .example.com without www. prefix might cause same problems? Is there any hack for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a cookie for `.localhost` makes no sense.

Simply check if the domain is 'localhost' and in this case do not add a leading dot.
Otherwise, '.domain.tld' is fine to set it for the domain and all its subdomains (most browsers handle cookies set for 'domain.tld' in the same way btw, but [the RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html) requires a leading dot).