# How do I use sessions across subdomains on localhost?

Tags: php, session, localhost

I am storing all sessions in MySQL via `session_set_save_handler`, but now I'd need to use sessions across subdomains on localhost. Does that even work on localhost?

I already added:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.localhost');
```

to my code, but that didn't seem to solve the problem either, probably because I am running the code on localhost. Or is there any workaround to be able to use it on localhost?

BTW, I am using XAMPP on Win7.

**Example:**

http://localhost has the session_id `2oog13m67rr1sd1gk94lbf1he2`

and

http://sub.localhost has the session_id `3vr0pdqljothmmf4btlenvk047`

So, I guess you just can't use `.localhost` for the `session.cookie_domain`.

Comment: Why not use the `hosts` file to set up a "proper" domain name like `mypc.local`? It probably chokes on `localhost` because it has only one component

Comment: I added `whatever.local` and it's working now. At least in Firefox, but not in Chrome, as already mentioned by Alvaro below. Thanks, Pekka!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already making up domain names, I suggest you don't reuse the top level domain. Either use one you own or invent a brand new one. The name `localhost` already has a well-defined meaning and that can lead to issues like the one you are facing. Particularly, browsers impose restrictions based on TLD's so you are not able to, e.g., set a cookie `.com` or `.co.uk`. I'm pretty sure that `localhost` has its own rules as well in most browsers.

**Update:** If you are using Chrome, see [this bug report](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/e0714b0e1bef5ec7?pli=1) resolved as *invalid*:

> You can only set domain cookies for registry controlled domains, i.e. 
>   something ending in .com or so, but not IPs or intranet hostnames like
>   localhost

Related question: [Localhost Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845050/localhost-cookie)

Comment: I'll test it then in Firefox instead. Thanks Alvaro!

Answer (score 2):

I tried setting cookies for .localhost.com and it worked.
You can add in your machine's hosts file an entry for localhost.com to point to 127.0.0.1
and then browser will forward cookies of localhost.com to http://sub.localhost.com.

It worked for me on node.js, I think similar thing should work on php as well